# Hash Join not behaving as required

Tags: sas, hashtable

I am using a hash join on some sample data to join a small table on a larger one. In this example '_1080544_27_08_2016' is the larger table and '_2015_2016_playerlistlookup' the smaller one. Here is my code:

```
data both(drop=rc);
 declare Hash Plan 
 (dataset: 'work._2015_2016_playerlistlookup');                             /* declare the name Plan for hash */
 rc = plan.DefineKey ('Player_ID');                                         /* identify fields to use as keys */
 rc = plan.DefineData ('Player_Full_Name', 
 'Player_First_Name', 'Player_Last_Name', 
 'Player_ID2');                                                                 /* identify fields to use as data */
 rc = plan.DefineDone ();                                                   /* complete hash table definition */
 do until (eof1) ;                                                          /* loop to read records from _1080544_27_08_2016 */
 set _1080544_27_08_2016 end = eof1;
 rc = plan.add ();                                                          /* add each record to the hash table */
 end;
 do until (eof2) ;                                                          /* loop to read records from _2015_2016_playerlistlookup */
 set _2015_2016_playerlistlookup end = eof2;
 call missing(Player_Full_Name, 
 Player_First_Name, Player_Last_Name);                                      /* initialize the variable we intend to fill */
 rc = plan.find ();                                                         /* lookup each plan_id in hash Plan */
 output;                                                                    /* write record to Both */
 end;
 stop;
run;
```

This is producing a table that has the same numbers of rows as the smaller, lookup table. What I would like to see if a table the same size as the larger one with the additional fields from the lookup table joined on via the primary key.

The larger table has repeating primary keys. That is to say the primary key is not unique (based on row number for example).

Can someone please tell me what I need to amend in the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are loading both datasets into your hash object - the small one when you declare it, and then the large one as well in your first do-loop. This makes no sense to me, unless you have lookup values already populated for some but not all of the rows in your large dataset, and you are trying to carry them over between rows.

You are then looping through the lookup dataset and producing 1 output row for each row of that dataset.

It is unclear exactly what you are trying to do here, as this is not a standard use case for hash objects.

Here's my best guess - if this isn't what you're trying to do, please post sample input and intended output datasets.

```
data want;
 set _1080544_27_08_2016;
 if 0 then set _2015_2016_playerlistlookup;
 if _n_ = 1 then do;
   declare Hash Plan(dataset: 'work._2015_2016_playerlistlookup');                             
   rc = plan.DefineKey ('Player_ID'); 
   rc = plan.DefineData ('Player_Full_Name', 'Player_First_Name', 'Player_Last_Name', 'Player_ID2');                                                                 
   rc = plan.DefineDone ();
 end;
 call missing(Player_Full_Name, Player_First_Name, Player_Last_Name);   
 rc = plan.find();
 drop rc;
run;
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. could you please give me so example code as i am not sure what you are saying. thanks.

Comment: I've made a guess at what you're trying to do - if that isn't what you want, please post some sample data.